# Can't get flowplayer started

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, flowplayer

I am trying to load a video in the flowplayer in my asp.net mvc app, using this documentation:
http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/installation/

my page looks like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js"></script>
<div id="flvContent" style="width: 80%; height: 300px;"></div>
<script>
    flowplayer("flvContent", "~/flowplayer.controls-3.2.15.swf", "sample_mpeg4.mp4");
</script>
```

how can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to get you started.

**Example**

```
<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js">
</script>

<a href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv"
   style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;"
   id="player">
</a>

<script>
    flowplayer("player", 
               "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");
</script>
```

And here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yaXFC/) of the code.

There are many more demos on the [demo area](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/index.html) of the flowplayer site.